# Issue with reading request body using spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am new to Java and Springboot, I am trying to create simple REST API to insert employee record into mysql database. Getting following error

```
@RequestBody => Employee [id=0, firstName=null, lastName=null, email=null]
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.saa.springboot.model.Employee.firstName] with root cause

org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.saa.springboot.model.Employee.firstName
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
```

Employee Class:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="employees")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    
    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
}
```

EmployeeController

```
package com.saa.springboot.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.saa.springboot.model.Employee;
import com.saa.springboot.service.EmployeeService;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/employees")
public class EmployeeController {
    
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    public EmployeeController(EmployeeService employeeService) {
        super();
        this.employeeService = employeeService;
    }
    
    @PostMapping()
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> saveEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
        System.out.println("@RequestBody => " + employee.toString());
        return new ResponseEntity<Employee>(employeeService.saveEmployee(employee), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
    
}
```

Application Properties:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ems_db?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = pwd
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

Curl Request:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST --data "{\"firstName\": \"john\", \"lastName\": \"cena\"}" "http://localhost:8080/api/employees"
```

From the `println` statement, we can clearly see field values(firstName, lastName and email) read as null using @RequestBody

```
@RequestBody => Employee [id=0, firstName=null, lastName=null, email=null]
```

I am not sure what I am missing here, I have tried with Postman as well without any luck, same error.

[image]
[image]

Any guidance is must appreciated.

Comment: Make a sure that you are using correct RequestBody annotation, because open-api has @RequestBody annotation too, you should not use this one. Assert that you are using @RequestBody from exactly `org.springframework.web.bind.annotation` package.

Comment: Do not use entities in the rest api. Learn about 3tier architecture.

Comment: Have you tried to use first_name in the json data.

Comment: this looks like a "cli quoting" issue to me... please try(tested in pwsh+bash): `--data '{"firstName": ...}'` (with enclosing single quotes `'` and (normal) double quotes '"' inside the json.

Comment: @Jens I have tried first_name as well, it too read as null from RequestBody

Comment: @xerx593 tried single quote wrapping of json body, got curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (3) unmatched close brace/bracket in URL position 5:
cena}'

Comment: @Sharofiddin I have used correct import as you mentioned.

Comment: what is your shell? the error (xp&circumstances) point (me) into this (curl) direction...

Comment: @xerx593 I have updated postman results as well, same error, I am sure its not the issue of cmd or curl command.

Comment: Can you share your application.properties or application.yml file?

Comment: Also please share your pom.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with Eclipse setup. The lombok library was not installed for eclipse due to this `@Data` annotation was not working on Employee class and hence no getters and setters. To solve, I installed lombok in eclipse installation folder and restarted it.